# How do I restart hadoop services on dataproc cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I may be searching with the wrong terms, but google is not telling me how to do this. The question is how can I restart hadoop services on Dataproc after changing some configuration files (yarn properties, etc)?

Services have to be restarted on a specific order throughout the cluster. There must be scripts or tools out there, hopefully in the Dataproc installation, that I can invoke to restart the cluster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configuring properties is a common and well supported use case.

You can do this via [cluster properties](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/cluster-properties), no daemon restart required. Example:

`dataproc clusters create my-cluster --properties yarn:yarn.resourcemanager.client.thread-count=100`

If you're doing something more advanced, like updating service log levels, then you can use `systemctl` to restart services.

First ssh to a cluster node and type `systemctl` to see the list of available services. For example to restart HDFS NameNode type `sudo systemctl restart hadoop-hdfs-namenode.service`

If this is part of initialization action then `sudo` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

On master nodes:

```
sudo systemctl restart hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager.service
sudo systemctl restart hadoop-hdfs-namenode.service
```

on worker nodes:

```
sudo systemctl restart hadoop-yarn-nodemanager.service
sudo systemctl restart hadoop-hdfs-datanode.service
```

After that, you can use `systemctl status <name>` to check the service status, also check logs in `/var/log/hadoop`.